# SQL Server Sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to sort dates in my SQL server but I am facing trouble sorting String field in the correct order. The query returns `Week 9 FY18` value in the column before `Week 52 FY18`.

How do I fix this problem in my query. This is the query I am using right now.

```
SELECT
    [Forecast Week],
    ProductGroup,
    Product,
    Week,
    [Ex Factory Supply Plan Total]
FROM
    anaplan.exfactorysupply_staging
WHERE
    ProductGroup IN (
                        'BEAM'
                    )
    AND Week = 'Week 19 FY18'
ORDER BY
    [Forecast Week] DESC;
```

Comment: can you post the schema \ create table for exfactorysupply_staging please

Comment: also, can you post some data too, I suggest using SQLFiddle

Comment: That is a very tough way to store a week value. I will once again fall back to my advice that a Calendar Table / Date Dimension would be a tremendous help to you.

Comment: You would be better off storing the week as a date, with a foreign key to a fiscal period (calendar) table that has the description of the period.

Comment: I agree with @Shawn - A Calendar Table is, hands down, probably the most useful analysis table you can have.  Of course, here you'd probably want an id for the week/year combo, not just dealing with the "first day of the week" date (although that works too)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use an actual date.  So, if you have a date column, just use:

```
order by forecast_week_date desc  -- or whatever the column is
```

Absent that, you can use the length trick, because your formats are so consistent:

```
order by len([Forecast Week]) desc, [Forecast Week] desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this if all your week data is stored in the same format (i.e. Week XX FY18):

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(REPLACE (Week, ' FY18',''), 'Week ',''))
```

Answer (score 0):

`Week 9 FY18` and `Week 52 FY18` are **string values**. As far as the database is concerned, they are *not dates*. Say it with me: Those. Values. Are. Not. Dates. When comparing them, the database compares them as strings, because *that's what they are*. It has no reason to do anything different.

The first different characters in either string are the `9` and the `5`. It doesn't matter the `9` and the `5` are semantically part of longer numbers within the string, because the database *only* looks at this as text. `9` is greater than `5`, so when sorting `DESC` *of course* `Week 9 FY18` comes before `Week 52 FY18`.

If you want the server to treat these values as dates, the best thing to do is **store them as dates**... store a `DateTime` column using midnight on the first day of the week for the value. This will make your `ORDER BY` expression naturally work as expected. This is just one of many things changing the column type will fix. Storing a date value as anything other than one of the date types is ***insane***.

If you want to see values that look like more like `Week 9 FY18`, that's fine. *But do that at the presentation level*... in a `SELECT` clause at the earliest, but ideally in the client programs, rather than on the database at all.